# How to display value at knob chart using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4, jquery-knob

1. How to display value that get from some URL using jQuery Knob Chart in Bootstrap 4. I got "NaN" value. (Please refer code below)
2. How to display "-" dash symbol if the data is null. (Please refer code below)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="knob" id="avg_temperature" data-width="120" data-height="120" data-thickness="0.40" data-fgColor="#000000" readonly>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url : XXX,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    dataSrc : 'data',
    contentType: false,
    processData: true,
    success: function(response){
        if (response.status == "Success"){            
            if (response.data[0]["avg_temperature"] == null){
                response.data[0]["avg_temperature"] = "-";
                $("#avg_temperature").text("-");
            }
            $("#avg_temperature").text(response.data[0]["avg_temperature"]);

            var colors = ['#11E117', '#FFC300', '#C00']

            //knob chart for temperature
            $('#avg_temperature').knob();
            $('#avg_temperature').attr('data-fgColor', '#11E117');

            $({animatedVal: 0}).animate({animatedVal: response},{
                duration: 3000,
                easing: "swing",
                async: false,
                step: function() {
                    var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal);
                    $("#avg_temperature").trigger('configure', {
                        'fgColor': colors[(val < 40) ? 0 : (val < 70) ? 1 : 2]
                    }).val(val).trigger("change");
                    var newVal = val + String.fromCharCode(176) + 'C'; $('#avg_temperature').val(newVal);
                }
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: This seems to work in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qzfw36ct/1/. Can you please add a working example of the issue to the question so we can create an MCVE. Note that the AJAX section can be removed as it's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: I already provide the code at that link. for HTML and JS. please let me know if that is not sufficient.

Comment: What is the value of `response`?

Comment: I created a variable `$("#avg_temperature").val = "90";` as the value.

Comment: No, I asked what is the value of the `response` argument in your `$.ajax` call. You're using this in the `animate()` method. I'm assuming it's an object, not an integer, hence your mistake. From the context it looks like you should be using `...animate({ animatedVal: parseInt(response.data[0]["avg_temperature"], 10) })`

Comment: You are amazing! It works! Please put that solution as Answer so I can vote up.

Comment: Added the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of your code it seems that `response` is an object, and this is the cause of the issue as `animate()` expects the value you provide to be an integer.

From the context of your usage of `response` elsewhere in the code it appears that you need to access a specific `temperature` property from it, like this:

```js
if (response.data[0]["avg_temperature"] == null)
    response.data[0]["avg_temperature"] = "-";

var colors = ['#11E117', '#FFC300', '#C00']

let $avgTemp = $("#avg_temperature").text(response.data[0]["avg_temperature"]);
$avgTemp.data('fgColor', '#11E117').knob();

$({
  animatedVal: 0
}).animate({
  animatedVal: parseInt(response.data[0]["avg_temperature"], 10) // update here
}, {
  duration: 3000,
  easing: "swing",
  step: function() {
    var val = Math.ceil(this.animatedVal);
    $avgTemp.trigger('configure', {
      'fgColor': colors[(val < 40) ? 0 : (val < 70) ? 1 : 2]
    }).val(val).trigger("change");

    var newVal = val + String.fromCharCode(176) + 'C';
    $avgTemp.val(newVal);
  }
});
```

Also note the removal of `async: false`. It's bad practice, and you don't need it here anyway

Comment: Hi, just wanna know what are the function of integer "10" use for at the the row of the answer?

Comment: It's the radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax

Comment: Hi, could you help me on this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236178/how-to-make-toggle-option-return-to-default-after-modal-event-close-happen