# How to make toggle option return to default after Modal event close happen?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

How to make toggle option return to default after Modal event close happen? I am trying by using `prop checked` but it is not working.

Tried below, but not working.

1. $('#on').prop('checked');
2. $('#on').prop('checked', false);
3. $('#off').prop('checked', true);

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="view_modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="switch_toggle">
            <input type="radio" id="off" name="status" value="inactive" checked>
            <label for="off" class="text-center">OFF</label>
            <input type="radio" id="on" name="status" value="active">
            <label for="on" class="right text-center">ON</label>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.switch_toggle label').on('click', function(){
    var indicator = $(this).parent('.switch_toggle').find('span');
    if ($(this).hasClass('right')){
        $(indicator).addClass('right');
        console.log("active")   //this is appear
    } else {
        $(indicator).removeClass('right');
        console.log("inactive")    //this is appear
    }
});

$("#view_modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#on').prop('checked', false);    //this is not working
    console.log("inactive modal 2")    //this is appear
});
```

Comment: Do you get anything in console? Try in plain: `document.getElementById('on').checked = false`

Comment: try $("#on").val(false);

Comment: @csandreas1, it is not working.

Comment: try this `setTimeout(() => {document.getElementById('on').checked = false}, 250)`

Comment: still same, nothing happen